# Simple Accordion scrolls to top after previously open div closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

This accordion consists of an unordered list that displays a div onclick. Clicking another list item closes the previously opened div. The issue I am having is that the content scrolls up (In Safari/iOS and Firefox) because the previous link is closed.

The "accordion" works as it should in Chrome, by not scrolling the div upwards after the previous link is closed – [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jasiostefanski/xpvt214o/39799/)

However, if you open the fiddle in either safari or Firefox you will see that the newly opened div scrolls to top.

To make things a little tricker, the accordion exists in a percentage-based div that is set to overflow:auto;

Does anyone know of a way to replicate Chromes behavior in Safari, Firefox, etc. ?

```js
$('.tog').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.tog').removeClass('active').next('div').hide();
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').slideToggle(250);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.structure {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  background: yellow
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  background: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.projCont {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="structure">
  <ul>
    <li class="shower" id="one">
      <a class="tog" href="#one" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 1</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="two">
      <a class="tog" href="#two" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 2</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="three">
      <a class="tog" href="#three" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 3</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="four">
      <a class="tog" href="#four" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 4</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="five">
      <a class="tog" href="#five" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 5</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="six">
      <a class="tog" href="#six" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 6</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="seven">
      <a class="tog" href="#seven" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 7</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="shower" id="eight">
      <a class="tog" href="#eight" onclick="return false;">
        <button>title of project 8</button>
      </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding current active panel (.hide()) without any transition and open new panel with a transition in 250ms delay (slideToggle(250)).

This is causing scrolling issue.

To fix this eighter you can have a transition to both panels in the same time frame or remove transition from both.

**Remove transition**

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.tog').removeClass('active').next('div').hide();
$(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').show();
```

**With transition**

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.tog').removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(250);
$(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').slideDown(250);
```

This can be written as follows and it's cleaner and easy to understand

```
$('.tog').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var isCurrentPanelActive = $(this).next('.projCont').hasClass('active');

  if (isCurrentPanelActive) {
    return;
  }

  $('.structure .active').slideUp();
  $(this).next('.projCont').slideDown().addClass('active');
});
```

Also, you don't need a button inside the anchor tag.

```
<ul>
    <li class="shower" id="one">
      <a class="tog">
                    title of project 1
             </a>
      <div class="projCont">
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I swapped the jQuery and removed the buttons but now the behavior is not working as it should. The links scroll up and the links above those clicked are no longer clickable: https://jsfiddle.net/jasiostefanski/hkomyw1n/4/. Also, when changing removing or adding transition to both the problem persists in Safari/iOS/Firefox.

Comment: It should scroll because you have href="#{value}" on links, So, page location changes when you click on the link and your page scroll is set to top. Try removing that

Comment: Removed: https://jsfiddle.net/jasiostefanski/hkomyw1n/7/ The problem(s) persist; links above those clicked are no longer working and the links scroll up when opened.